# session_regster after sanitizing input?

Tags: php

```
$username = $_POST['myusername'];
$password = $_POST['mypassword'];    
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($username));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($password));
session_register("username");
session_register("password");
```

I have these lines in my code it's not the full structure but it's the relevant part.  Session_register(); is deprecated and the right way to do it is like: `$_SESSION['username'] = 'username';`

But I'm still not sure if it's correct.  I'm sort of worried because I really need to sanitize the input. (I'm trying to use the $_SESSION['username'] = 'username'; and get out of deprecated functions)

Thanks.

Comment: Sanitize the data for what?! Depending on the usage it is done with different functions. And it is always a bad idea to try to implement *universal* sanitizing function that will protect you agains anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to sanitize input.

**You should sanitize output**

mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with sessions. it's mysql related function and should be used to build mysql query only.

as for the username and password, I see no use for storing it in a session.
You have to verify it against database, and then store only user id in the session.

and you should not use stripslashes unconditionally, as it may spoil your data. better turn magic quotes off in php.ini and get rid of this function at all.

Comment: Thanks I removed it.  If I do verify username and password should I start a completely new session like `$_SESSION['authenticated'] = $username; ?`
Or what do you mean by user id?

Comment: Don't you have an autoincrement field in your users table? that's what I call user id and it should be stored in a session. something like `$_SESSION['authenticated'] = $row['id'];`

Comment: Ohhh. Yes I do have a id table I thought you meant something else. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you should be using `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`

**NOTE**  This is assuming you want to assign the $username variable to the session. This has nothing to do with sanitizing.

Comment: OHHHH, silly me.  I thought something completely different.  Thanks dude.

Comment: That's very common for this site. Although being literally correct, your answer fails to grasp entire problem and as a result it helps nothing. There is absolutely no sense in storing $_POST['mypassword'] in a session. Don't you see it?

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of that. But I'd have hoped that my note would have been self explanatory